# How to use contact Contentprovider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

```
package com.Kiro.Test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;

public class TestActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Uri uri=People.CONTENT_URI;
        String projection[]=new String[]{People._ID,People.NAME,People.NUMBER};
        Cursor cur=this.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int id=cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        do{
            System.out.print(cur.getString(id));
            System.out.println("");
        }while(cur.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

when I run this code in my emulator,the logcat find ***CursorIndexoutofBoundsException*** 
   can you help me work out this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems problem is here:

```
  do{
            System.out.print(cur.getString(id));
            System.out.println("");
        }while(cur.moveToNext());
```

you need to first call cur.moveToFirst() to set cursor on 0th Position:

```
cur.moveToFirst();
  while(cur.hasNext(){
            cur.moveToNext();
            System.out.print(cur.getString(id));
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "do while" try with the while because do while run at least once even condition is false.

```
while(cur.moveToNext()){  
System.out.print(cur.getString(id));
System.out.println("");
}
```

My be this was the problem.